# What does "Feature doesn't have a geometry" mean in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry

When I open the .shp file and click on specfic item in the attribute table, in the canvas, it said "Feature doesn't have a geometry". Is it the same as "geometry is not valid", or does it simply mean there is no related data?

Comment: The shapefile specification permits null (zero vertex) shapes.  This is ***not*** the same as being invalid (which could mean many different things), and shouldn't generate an error message.